# how insert a datetime in mongoose js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongoose

How can I insert a datetime in mongoose js?, I know a datetime is a Date in Schema.

This is my schema:

```
 const mongoose = require('mongoose');
 const { Schema } = mongoose;

 const todoSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    description: String,
    isDone: Boolean,
    createdAt: Date,
    updatedAt: Date
   });
  mongoose.model('todos', todoSchema);
```

This is my post route:

```
 app.post('/api/todos', async (req, res) => {

      const { name, description, isDone,createdAt,updatedAt} = req.body;

        const todo = new Todo({
                    name,
                    description,
                    isDone,
                    createdAt,
                    updatedAt
                              });

                try {
                    let newTodo = await todo.save();
                     res.status(201).send(newTodo);
                     } catch (err) {
                        if (err.name === 'MongoError') {
                              res.status(409).send(err.message);
                             }
                             res.status(500).send(err);
                             }
                     });
```

This is my date time picker input:

```
  import React from 'react';
  import DateTimePicker from 'react-widgets/lib/DateTimePicker';
  import Moment from 'moment';
  import momentLocalizer from 'react-widgets-moment';

 Moment.locale('en');

 momentLocalizer();

 const DateTimePickerInput = ({
     label,
     input,
     format,
     width,
     placeholder,
     defaultValue,
     meta: { touched, error },
   }) => {
        return (
                <div className='form-group'>
                <label forname={input.name}>{label}</label> <br />
                  <DateTimePicker
                     placeholderText={placeholder}
                     className='form-control'
                      />
                <div className='text-danger' style={{ marginBottom: '20px' }}>
                {touched && error}
                 </div>
                  </div>
                      );
                       };
           export default DateTimePickerInput;
```

And this my todo form with date time picker field:

```
       <Field
            name='createdAt'
            component={DateTimePickerInput}
            dateFormat='dd-MM-yyyy'
            // dateFormat='dd-MM-yyyy H:mm'
            // showTimeSelect
            // timeFormat='HH:mm'
            placeholder='todoCreatedAt...'
            label='CreatedAt'
             />
          <Field
               name='updatedAt'
               component={DateTimePickerInput}
               dateFormat='dd-MM-yyyy'
               // dateFormat='dd-MM-yyyy H:mm'
               // showTimeSelect
               //timeFormat='HH:mm'
               placeholder='todoUpdatedAt...'
               label='UpdatedAt'
                 />
```

How can I insert a datetime, in this case, createdAt and updatedAt in data base. Maybe I'm doing wrong post route. 
I expect createdAt and updatedAt saved in database but real output those data are not saved in database.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For createdAt and updatedAt, use mongoose's timestamp options in schema. It will take care of timestamps automatically. Your schema will look like this after using the option.

`const todoSchema = new Schema({ name: String, ...}, { timestamps: true });`

[Read more here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#timestamps)

Comment: I did it this way and doesn't work. const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { Schema } = mongoose;

const todoSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  description: String,
  isDone: Boolean,
  createdAt: {type: Date},
  updatedAt: {type: Date}
  },
  {timestamps: true}
  );

mongoose.model('todos', todoSchema);

Comment: You don't have to explicitly add the updatedAt and createdAt in schema after using timestamps option.

Comment: I'm confused. Timestamps option I'm declaring after schema.

Comment: Your new schema should look like this. const todoSchema = new Schema({ name: String, description: String, isDone: Boolean }, { timestamps: true } ); Also, you need to create a new document to test this. Old documents will not get updated automatically.

Comment: How can I create new document?, I deleted created_at and updated_at from schema and post route.

Comment: This is how your schema should look like https://gist.github.com/Jaskaranrehal/593de5f82dcab1ca4eea7e53f44ea7b8. Now after you change the schema, try to create a new item in the database to see the changes, old data will not be changed automatically.

Comment: And how should look my post route?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205843/discussion-between-francisco-arias-and-jaskaran-singh).